# No Notification when App sends event Invites via Open Graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

My code looks something like this...

```
FB.api('/'+eventId+'/invited?users='+selectedFriends.join(','), 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured, please try again. ('+JSON.stringify(response.error)+')');
                  } else {
                    alert('Invites Sent! ' + response.id);
                  }
                });
```

It sends invites, however the users don't receive a notification. The only way the user knows that she was invited to the event is to check her Event list. I want to notify the user somehow -- an email, wall post, or app request comes to minds -- but I don't want to spam my users. How would you suggest dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use invites then. Invites are specifically intended to appear in a user event list. But since you don't want to spam your users, your other options (email/wall post/app request) won't work either, because they're inevitably leading to spam by nature...

So make your choice: invites - recommended way but no active notification, or email/wall post/app request - likely to be considered as spam but active notification.

I'd advise to use invites and not to worry about users being actively notified. They are recommended by Facebook, fall into their game framework, and even if the notification is not obvious, the method has proven to be quite effective for most apps until now ;)