# Inviting users to an event - notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an exsiting event which I'm trying to invite users to using this method:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/events.invite
?eid=EID
&uids=UIDS
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

...this sort of works, in that the invited user gets a post to their wall like this:

```
Test Event — 19 March at 14:08.
User invited you · View · Join
```

But my problem is, the invited user DOESN'T get a notification.

The code is taken from here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.invite/

But when I run if from there, which is identical to my above code, the invited user DOES get a notification.

What am I doing wrong / missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated method and should switch to using graph api requests.

In this case, you can use the [Event object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) in the graph.
Doing the same thing with the graph api should look something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID
or
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3
```

(You should have the create_event permission and an active access token of course)

This is copied from the document, under the *invited* section. You might also might want to check the *attending*, *maybe* and *declined* sections.

You can use the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) tool to test graph calls.

---

## Edit

I'm sorry for not including this with my original answer:

The invitation made by the graph api (or the deprecated REST) does not result in notifications in the users' side.
You can find a few more threads about this subject here:

- [Invite user(s) to event with notification - works manually but not with Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554997/invite-users-to-event-with-notification-works-manually-but-not-with-graph-ap)
- [Facebook: No Notification when App sends event Invites via Open Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043950/facebook-no-notification-when-app-sends-event-invites-via-open-graph)
- [invite for an event by graph api doesn't send notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021776/invite-for-an-event-by-graph-api-doesnt-send-notification)

But the best indication for this being the case can be found in this bug ticket: [Bugs - No Notifications on Event invites via Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/300710046628101).
Notice the response from facebook:

> event invites do not currently render an on-site notification, this is
>   a deliberate limitation of the API Event invites made this way will
>   still increment the counter in the 'events' bookmark and add the event
>   to the user's events list

Hope this clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the newer method, but that does the same - it invites the user but doesn't produce a notification in the users notification which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to approach that... Modified my original answer with that info.

Comment: Brilliant, thorough answer. Thank you.